# vb.net serialization classes

Tags: vb.net, serialization

I'm working on a project that will need an Save/load function. I'm looking at two possible ways:

- Make my own functions that do the saving/loading => making my 'own' filestructure to keep everything in place (much much work)
- use serialization of some kind

In my current test project I implemented serialization, but when I update a class, the whole project is unreadable because it can't be processed by the deserialization... Making it very hard to use if I want files to be backwards compatible.

At this moment i use this approach:

```
<System.Serializable()> _
Public MustInherit Class clsCompo
    Implements ISerializable

    ...

    Public Sub GetObjectData(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, ByVal context As StreamingContext) Implements ISerializable.GetObjectData
        info.AddValue("properties", Me._properties, GetType(CustomPropertyCollection))
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, ByVal context As StreamingContext)
        Me._properties = DirectCast(info.GetValue("properties", GetType(CustomPropertyCollection)), CustomPropertyCollection)
   End Sub
End Class
```

I'm quite lost in all this because I find it hard to handle, especially when using more than 30 different classes that all need to be serializable.

What I'm really after is a point in the "good" direction to implement a Save/Load feature that can be backwards compatible and can save different classes all in one file

EDIT:
Eventually, I found a project similar to what I needed: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30270/XML-Serialization-of-Complex-NET-Objects

It's similar to what has been posted below.

Comment: Deserializing into a changed class is only an issue with the BinaryFormatter.  XMLSerialization and ProtoBuf-NET do not have that problem.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method I've had reasonable long-term results with is to enforce (now and forever) your own contract that every class has at least a Version property, which when combined with the type gives you a unique identifier to later tell you how to deserialize to an object. You may also want to create objects from different classes depending on the version # of your stored data, so don't do the versioning within the class, do it with eg a Persister object which works on any object implementing your stateful interface:

First use an application-wide Enum for your application's fundamental object types (not each class):

```
Public Enum MyObjectTypesEnum
    Unspecified = 0
    Fish = 1
    Cow = 2
End Enum
```

Then your interface:

```
Public Interface IStateful
    ReadOnly Property Version As Integer
    ReadOnly Property ObjectType As MyObjectTypesEnum
    Sub SetState(Info As SerializationInfo)
    Sub GetState(Info As SerializationInfo)
End Interface
```

Step 1 in persisting your objects is to store the version and type:

```
Public Sub SaveTheBasics(Info As SerializationInfo, TheObject as IStateful)
    Info.SetInt64(TheObject.Version,"Version")
    Info.SetInt64(TheObject.ObjectType,"ObjectType")
```

This stores all the information you need to cope with different versions in the future:

```
Dim TheObject as IStateful

Select Case Info.GetInt64("ObjectType") 
Case MyObjectTypesEnum.Fish
    Select Case Info.GetInt64("Version")
    Case Is < 2
        TheObject = New OldestFishClass
    Case Is < 5
        TheObject = New OldFishClass
    Case Else
        TheObject = New NewFishClass
    End Select
Case MyObjectTypesEnum.Cow
    ...
End Select
TheObject.SetState(Info)

etc etc.
```

If your application's policy is to insist the data is stored in the latest version, then when loading and upgrading from a previous version's data, you can instantiate the old class, and use that in your newest class's overloaded loading method to upgrade:

```
    Select Case Info.GetInt64("Version")
    ...
    Case Is < 5
        Dim TempOldObject As New OldFishClass
        TempOldObject.SetState(Info)
        TheObject = New NewFishClass
        TheObject.SetState(TempOldObject)
    Case Else
        TheObject = New NewFishClass
        TheObject.SetState(Info)
    End Select
    ...
```

...and make sure your new class knows how to load from its previous version as below.

You can use a base class which implements the Interface for all your stateful objects, and also has any properties all your objects may need:

```
Public MustInherit Class MyBaseClass
   Implements IStateful
   Public MustOverride Readonly Property VersionNumber As Integer Implements IStateful.Version
   Public MustOverride Readonly Property ObjectType As MyObjectTypesEnum Implements IStateful.ObjectType
   Public UniqueID As GUID

...

Public Class NewFishClass
    Inherits MyBaseClass
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property VersionNumber As Integer
      Get
        Return 5
      End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ObjectType As MyObjectTypesEnum
      Get
        Return MyObjectTypesEnum.Fish
      End Get
    End Property
    'Overloaded state-setting methods (could be Constructors instead):
    Public Sub SetState(Info As SerializationInfo)
        Me.ScaleCount = Info.GetInt64("ScaleCount")
    End Sub
    Public Sub SetState(OldFish As OldFishClass)
        'Upgrade from V2:
        Me.ScaleCount = OldFish.LeftScales + OldFish.RightScales
    End Sub
    Public Sub SetState(OldestFish As OldestFishClass)
        'Upgrade from V1
        Me.ScaleCount = OldFish.Length * OldFish.ScalesPerUnitLength)
    End Sub
etc etc.
```

The overriding principle here is that the contract is contained in Interfaces, and as much as possible the base class does the necessary work of complying with that contract. Then to create your 30 classes you inherit each from the base object. If you've built it right you'll be forced to provide the information necessary for correct versioning and persistance (you're also building in abstraction layers, which of course at some point you'll be grateful for).

In larger projects I extend this sort of thinking so that each object's persistable properties are held in a "State" object which derives from a base "StateBase" class which itself implements an IState interface. Persistance then acts on any StateBase object. I also use a CollectionBase class (which also inherits from my base class) which handles instantiating and filling contained objects. Often your objects need to store references to each other across sessions, so everything needs a unique ID (GUID) to recreate those references - which goes in your base object.

Comment: I'm working my through this, But don't really grasp the idea. So you load the version number and depending on this version you initialize a class which handles this data? So to be eable to use the new version of the class I must "translate" the old data to the new class and save it with the new class. Can you provide a little test project illustrating your workflow on the large projects? I think i might go that route.

Comment: Once it's all working it's likely not so "little" by some standards, there's a fair bit of coding, which is the penalty for the flexibility. How upgrading is handled depends on your application lifetime policy: once you install version 2, does it automatically save V1 data in V2 format? Or do you keep using V1 objects etc? If upgrading, then each class and the persistence code should be modified. I'll edit my answer above a bit.

Comment: This question explains a little more about the issues involved with references - I agree with the accepted answer. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026238/net-xmlserializer-and-multiple-references-to-the-same-object). The methodology I use is to pool all objects by ID (GUID) in a global dictionary during deserialization, then traverse the entire model again recreating the object references.

Comment: Without knowing the style, size and plans for the application, it's hard to know whether a simpler solution is a better choice for you. I'm not going to pretend that the full real-world implementation of all this isn't a serious investment, so if Plutonix's comment can work for you, I would say by all means use that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop your Data Access you receive xml from your stored procedures and stream into your objects through your DAL.  Then take your stored procedure xml data and serializes it into the object.

Dim obj as New YourObjectType

obj =  ConvertFromXml(xml.ToString(), GetType(YourObjectType) ,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

```
Public Shared Function ConvertFromXml(ByVal xml As String, ByVal objType As System.Type, ByVal encoding As System.Text.Encoding) As Object

    Dim o As Object = Nothing


    Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(objType)
    Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(xml))
        Using xr As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(ms)
            o = serializer.Deserialize(xr)
        End Using
    End Using



    Return o
End Function
```